# Генератор чисел из числа

Tags: php, javascript

Где можно найти или как можно сделать генератор чисел из числа? На пример у меня есть число 66, мне нужно разбросать его на X частей, чтобы при сложении всех этих частей получилось то же самое число.

Comment: А какие условия налагаются на числа? Если никаких, берёте `X - 1` штук единиц, и одну штуку `66 - Х + 1`. Или вообще `X - 1` штук нулей, и одну штуку `66`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короче, в коде проще написать чем на словах :)

```
var out = [],
    X= 8,
    Y = 111111;
for (var i = X-1; i > 0; i--) {
    var p = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Y - i))+1;
    Y -= p;
    out.push(p);
}
out.push(Y);
console.log(out);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rgHL6/

это если нет других ограничений.

[вот так поровнее выглядит, но смещается в начало](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rgHL6/3/)

Comment: а откуда, собственно, сомнения?

Comment: jvas != javascript вы наверное еще много чего не понимаете.

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё одна идея, для более равномерного распределения (извините, только идея):

1. Пусть `X` — количество чисел, `Y` — желаемая сумма.
2. Генерируем `X` случайных чисел от 0 до 1.
3. Суммируем их, пускай `S` — их сумма.
4. Положим `K = Y / S`, домножим все случайные числа на K
5. Если необходимо *целые* числа, округляем, и если надо подогнать сумму, модифицируем последнее слагаемое.